# How to create a SteppedComboBox with nimbus look&feel

Tags: java, swing

I need to use **SteppedComboBox** to display long string with a shorter **JComboBox** under **Nimbus L&F**. I found this nice [example code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/SteppedComboBoxExample.htm),  but it is for **Metal L&F**. It doesn't look good under **Nimbus L&F**.

By looking at the Java API for **Nimbus**, **JComboxBox**, and **ComboBoxUI** classes, I cannot figure out how to customize it by myself.

---

#### Solved

I think I have figured out how to make it working for Nimbus now. Use SynthComboBoxUI instead of MetalComboBoxUI

Comment: Use the NimbusLookAndFeel class instead of the metal?

Comment: You should put that down as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Combo Box Popup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/).

It supports this type of functionality and you don't need a custom UI.